# Angular Factory to share web api 2 token with multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a factory that gets a token from a web api and then shares that token with multiple controllers.  I've tried my best to create the factory and inject it into the controller but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly yet?  I'm getting an angular 'unknown provider' error.  Please advise, new to angular.  Thank you.

```
securityApp.factory('getToken', function ($scope, $http) {

var token = "";

$http({
    method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:62791/token', data: { username: $scope.userName, password: $scope.password, grant_type: 'password' }, transformRequest: function (obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    token = data.access_token;
    return token;
});      

});
```

---

```
securityApp.controller('membersController', function ($scope, $http, getToken) {

$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/?access_token=' + getToken.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken.token } })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.members = response.data;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A service can't be injected with `$scope`. Only controllers can. The only scope that can be injected in a service is the `$rootScope`. You need to pass the user name and the password to your service when calling it. It can't bet the user name and password from nowhere.

PS: when you ask about an error, post the complete and exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your factory not return any thing ([Read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)). Its should be like this

```
securityApp.factory('getToken', function ($scope, $http) {


return {
    getAccessToken: function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:62791/token', data: { username: $scope.userName, password: $scope.password, grant_type: 'password' }, transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              return data.access_token;
        });

    },
};
```

});

and call it in your controller like below.

```
securityApp.controller('membersController', function ($scope, $http, getToken) {

$scope.token = getToken.getAccessToken();
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token } })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.members = response.data;
    });
```

});

**Update:**
To solve the error: "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider change the code

```
securityApp.controller('membersController', ['$scope', '$http','getToken', function ($scope, $http, getToken) {

$scope.token = getToken.getAccessToken();
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token} })
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.members = response.data;
});
```

} ]);

[Demo Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/15/)

Comment: I changed my code with your suggestions.  I now get this error: "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- getToken
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20getToken
minErr/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:78:5

Comment: As suggested by Nizet above I removed $scope from the factory parameters / dependencies and that has resolved the unknown provider error.

Comment: The problem now is that the factory does not return anything to controller when called.  The factory gets the token from the server but the controller gets a blank token from the factory.

Comment: this is getting really complicated, I think I will have to use the $q service now to make this work.  Not something I know how to do.

Comment: Change the controller securityApp.controller('membersController',["getToken", function ($scope, $http, getToken) {

$scope.token = getToken.getAccessToken();
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token } })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.members = response.data;
    });
}]);